# Please help identify this set with red, black, and lime colors?

Tags: set-identification

Can someone tell me what it is so I can get instructions for it. All pieces are shown. I removed a couple I hope can help identify it[image][image][image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the printed Atlantis part, this looks like [Neptune Carrier (8075-1)](https://brickset.com/sets/8075-1/Neptune-Carrier).

[image: set image]

[image: vehicle out]

[image: vehicle]